# extracting numbers or changing them directly using perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
$harddisk = `wmic logicaldisk get size,caption`;
```

contains the following. What i want to do is extract the numbers, or change them directly

```
Total Hard disk capacity: 
Caption  Size          
C:       480737488896  
D:       19157479424   
E:                     
F:
```

would it be possible to perhaps get them using a foreach+

`foreach($harddisk =~ m/\d+/g){
    push(@hdd, noideawhattoputhere;
}`

or is it perhaps possible to use math in a regex? here i'd want to divide $1 by 1024.

```
$harddisk =~ s/(\d+)/$1/g;
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$harddisk =~ s|\d+|$&/1024|ge;
```

The `e` modifier means to treat the substitution as an expression to evaluate.